# MP4 to DVD - suggestion for workflow

Tags: mp4, vegas-pro, workflow

After a break of a few years I have started doing video editing again. So I bought Sony Vegas and later upgraded it to the latest version.

For this particular project my source files was created by two different devices: A Samsung Galaxy S2 mobile phone (mp4) and a Sony Cybershot camera (also mp4). The files from the Sony camera cannot be read directly by Vegas, so I have had to transcode them (they are still mp4).

I wanted to produce a DVD of this event (a birthday party), but when I render the project (to be used by DVD Architect) Vegas crashes for me halfway through the process.

I have of course reported this to Sony, but i don't expect any solution soon, so I was wondering if I was doing this the wrong way.

In this case - when the source is mp4 (and in a higher resolution than DVD) - would you suggest another workflow? Would it be better to transcode the files before I add them to the Vegas project?

Comment: That's weird.  I combined 2 video sources (iphone and Panasonic DMC-ZS1) into one in Vegas Pro 10 and they're not even the same size/resolution.

Comment: I can't understand it either. I have tried it in both version 12 and 13 (64 bit) and get the same error. It freezes and eventually crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a bad idea to have resolution and bit depth to spare during post but if you don't need the extras -- higher bit depth for cleaner effects / color grading, higher res for crop and blowup and so on -- then you can reduce the originals to the final output values with no loss of fidelity.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I should probably convert all the files to mpeg2 (pal dvd resolution) before editing. But what if I later wanted to burn a Blu-ray instead of a DVD? Are they any codecs/formats/containers that are more suitable to use as input to Vegas than others?

Comment: If Vegas has a proxy mode you could edit at proxy resolution and output at any resolution supported by the originals. And many editing systems let you use the decisions / timeline from your downscaled materials to later conform a version using the original materials. Since I don't use Vegas I can't say whether it allows either option.